# Why i am getting heap memory issue while selecting record using queryForList() of JdbcTemplate

Tags: spring

while selecting large record (above 4000) using below code I am facing heap memory issue.

I have increase heap sizeof JVM upto 4 GB

```
query = "select * from  tablename where folderindex is not null and checkflag!='1' and trunc(creation_date) < trunc(sysdate-"+no_OFDays+") order by UNIQUE_ID asc";

        ds = DBConnection.getDbConnection();
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
        rows = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query);
        logger.info("NO Documents at mount point: "+rows.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

how many row of table?
first if many row, you must adapt `fetch_size`. then, it will make a network call for `fetch_size`.

second, use `jdbcTemplete.query("...", new RowCallbackHandler() { ... })`.